# Inserting large BLOB into Oracle database

Tags: c#, oracle, blob

Oracle's [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/oralob.htm#CHDFHHHG) has a sample on how to insert large BLOBs, in Java. Is it possible to do the same in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A answer with a stream:

```
string path = @"D:\testfile.txt";
System.IO.FileStream myStream = new System.IO.FileStream(@path, FileMode.Open);

BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(myStream);
byte[] data = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)myStream.Length); //read the stream into byte

String sql =  "INSERT INTO testblob (testid, testblob) VALUES (100, :blobtodb)";       

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.CommandText = sql; // Set the sql-command
cmd.Connection = con; //con is an OracleConnection, create it before

OracleParameter param = cmd.Parameters.Add("blobtodb", OracleDbType.Blob); //Add the parameter for the blobcolumn
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input; 

param.Value = data; //Asign the Byte Array to the parameter
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //You are done!
```

This should work with every stream ;)

---

For Files with (over) 1TB:

**WARNING: Use the OPs Solution for big files, as it is really hard to have 1TB in Memory ;)**

Honestly I don't know, I can't try it here with such a big file. However `BLOB`s are [specified by Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits001.htm#i287903) with: `Maximum size: (4 GB - 1) * DB_BLOCK_SIZE initialization parameter (8 TB to 128 TB)`. So from database-side it should work.
But you *MAYBE* need to take care about the `Connection Timeout` and the `Connection Lifetime`, as it will take a long time to transfer such a big file over the network (I guess, I don't know your setup).

Comment: Actually I think I found what I was looking for - you need to create an OracleBlob, stream your large content into it (Oracle will be streaming it into the db) and then assign the OracleBlob as a parameter to the connection, at which point it gets actually written to the table

Comment: Mhm okay, that sounds good. Sure that the above wont also work? What I also usually do, use a reader, read the BLOB-column from database with `FOR UPDATE` at the end of the query, then get the OracleBlob with the reader like: `OracleBlob BLOB1 = reader.GetOracleBlob(int_blob_columnnumber);` and use `BLOB1.Write(data, index, lenght)` then ... (with using a transaction)

Comment: The main issue I have here is how to insert a blob that cannot possibly be held entirely in memory.

Comment: Yeah, hard to hold 1 TB in Memory ... May you can post a working example then ?

Comment: I will as soon as I get it actually working well. Thank you for your suggestions and comments!

Comment: byte[] data = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)myStream.Length);

This line allocates exactly as much memory as the file's size. So why the arbitrary 1 TB?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, set your parameter up like so:

```
var param = cmd.Parameters.Add("blobInParam", OracleDbType.Blob);
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;   

// Assign Byte Array to Oracle Parameter
param.Value = blobData;
```

Comment: And I have in my head that the bytes must always be a even number, right?. *just adding, maybe worth to know*

Comment: Can't honestly say that I've ever seen that limitation; that doesn't mean it isn't there, though!

Comment: How do you set a binary stream to the blob, such as OutputStream outstream = blob.setBinaryStream(1L); ?

Comment: @AllanElder that was a mistake from me, only `CLOB`s need to have a even number of bytes! `BLOB`s not!

Comment: Ah .. that would make sense, 2 bytes for every character.